# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.colors.red')

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

I'm new at react-native and try to build an app. When I run my code I'm getting this error:
[image]

Also colors code is here..........................................................................................................................................................

```
const NAMED_COLORS = {
  white: '#FFFFFF',
  grey: '#e5e5e5',
  gray_10: '#9f9f9f',
  black: '#2a2a2a',
  black_10: '#030303',

  red: '#cf2026',
  blue: '#3b5998',
  orange: '#ff9a00',
};

const THEME_COLORS = {
  ...NAMED_COLORS,

  text: NAMED_COLORS.black,
};

function colorWithAlpha(name: string = 'blue', opacity: number = 1) {
  if (!THEME_COLORS[name]) {
    name = 'blue';
  }

  return THEME_COLORS[name].split(', 1)').join(`, ${opacity})`);
}

export default {
  ...THEME_COLORS,
  colorWithAlpha,
};
```

The code I use 'color.red':

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';

import TabBarItem from '../../components/TabBarItem/TabBarItem';
import { SearchIcon, VisionIcon, FashTagIcon } from '../../components/Icons/Icons';

import { DUYGU_PROFILE } from '../../constants/imagesCostants';
import { TABS } from '../../constants/navigationContants';
import { colors } from '../../theme/colors';
import { isIphoneX } from '../../utils/isIphoneX';

function ProfileIcon() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.avatarWrapper}>
      <Image source={DUYGU_PROFILE} style={styles.avatar} />
    </View>
  );
}

const TABBAR_ICONS = {
  [TABS.HOME]: FashTagIcon,
  [TABS.BLOG]: VisionIcon,
  [TABS.GET_PAID]: VisionIcon,
  [TABS.SEARCH]: SearchIcon,
  [TABS.PROFILE]: ProfileIcon,
};

class MainTabBar extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            {navigation.state.routes.map((tab, index) => {
              const tabName = tab.routeName;
              const active = navigation.state.index === index;
              const IconComponent = TABBAR_ICONS[tabName];

              return (
                <TabBarItem
                  active={active}
                  key={tab.key}
                  tabName={tabName}
                  titleId={tabName}
                  icon={
                    <IconComponent
                      width={30}
                      height={30}
                      color={active ? colors.red : colors.gray_10}
                    />
                  }
                  onNavigate={() => navigation.navigate(tabName)}
                  navigation={navigation}
                />
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MainTabBar;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    bottom: isIphoneX ? 50 : 30,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    zIndex: 999,
    height: 50,
  },
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    zIndex: 9,
    shadowColor: colors.gray_10,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 45,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.7,
    shadowRadius: 16.0,

    elevation: 24,
  },
  avatarWrapper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
  },
});
```

What should I do?

Comment: where do you call colors.red ? can you share its instance ?

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I've edited my code, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a default export so change your import from

```
import { colors } from '../../theme/colors';
```

to

```
import colors from './colors';
```